# In play framework 2.x, how to add a global action/filter?

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, locale

More specifically, I need to allow passing a locale in the url then change the locale. This should be a global behavior and must happen before any action is called so that the locale change takes effect from the current request.

The `GlobalSettings.onRequest()` does not have `Http.Context` bound yet and as far as I know it does not have an API for changing the locale at that stage.

I could have an action that changes the locale, but I do not know how to make it global so that all requests go to that action first,and I dont want to annotate every controller as it is very easily forgotten.

I'm using play framework 2.1.2, any pointer would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are couple of options.

1. You can annotate controller classes and use Action composition

http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.2/JavaActionsComposition

1. Override the GlobalSettings.onRequest with following

   ```
    @Override
    public Action onRequest(Request request, Method actionMethod) {
        return new Action.Simple() {
           public Result call(Context ctx) throws Throwable {
             **//do your lang changing stuff**
             return delegate.call(ctx);
           }
        };
    }
   ```

Comment: thanks for the nice solution - overriding the onRequest.

Comment: for completeness I would just suggest this simple "lang changing stuff":
`String langString = request.getQueryString("lang"); if (langString != null) {ctx.changeLang(langString);}`. It allows you to add `?lang=de` to your url once and switch your session to German.

Else, thank you a lot for this solution. Have been searching far too long for it!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you are using scala or java.

This is one way to accomplish a header update of the language field in scala:

```scala
import play.api.mvc.{Headers, Handler, RequestHeader}
import play.api.http.HeaderNames
import play.api.GlobalSettings

object Global extends GlobalSettings {

  val LangQueryString = "lang"

  def updateLanguageHeader(lang: String)(request: RequestHeader) =
    request.copy(
      headers = new Headers {
        val data = (request.headers.toMap + (HeaderNames.ACCEPT_LANGUAGE -> Seq(lang))).toList
      })

  def remLangQueryString(request: RequestHeader) =
    request.copy(
      queryString = request.queryString - LangQueryString)

  def updateLangFromQueryString(request: RequestHeader) =
    request.getQueryString(LangQueryString) match {
      case Some(lang) =>
        (updateLanguageHeader(lang) _ andThen remLangQueryString)(request)
      case _ =>
        request
    }

  override def onRouteRequest(request: RequestHeader): Option[Handler] = {
    super.onRouteRequest(updateLangFromQueryString(request))
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, that could work, but i think the accepted answer is more appropriate. Cheers

Comment: The difference is that the answer of Nilanjan focuses on Java. This answer is scala related.

Comment: Hi, your idea is to change the request Accept-Language header while Nilanjan's uses the standard play action composition and change the locale before any other action is called. Both solutions work in either java or scala in this case, but personally I prefer the action composition as it can be extended to add other global actions easily.